# Image Bending transform in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I think we cannot have any bending transform in iOS, not even with 3D transformations, 
but can we define some transformation matrix and acheive it?

Or how do we draw images to a spherical/cylindrical context in OpenGL ES? 
I'd like to bend images in my iPhone app.

And this bending is variable dependend on the curvature of the context.

A typical example would be a photo on a mug.

All your help is appreciated.

Comment: It's called `image warping` - maybe some info here: http://www.google.com/search?q=image+warping+"iOS" - have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've came to an end in this. Instead of going for Open GLES , I used the ImageMagick Library which was very helpful.

Also I found a bash script to warp the images in cylindrical shapes using ImageMagick C APIs.

[Refer Cylinderize Script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php). Just thought that it might be usefull to someone. Cheers.

Comment: Make sure you accept your own answer to resolve this question!

Comment: I have to make the same effect, could you help me more on this.

Comment: There is a Wave function in ImageMagick C Api. That will help you. Cheers.

Comment: Will you give me the source code of how to use Wave Function for change image in Cylindrical shape?