# How to stretch image into custom shape (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, shapes, uibezierpath

[image]

The code list below crops the image. I would like the image to be transformed/ stretched and not cropped in the shape. All of the image contents are still in the transformed picture. It will just look different.

```
extension UIImageView {
func addMask(_ bezierPath: UIBezierPath) {
    let pathMask = CAShapeLayer()
    pathMask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.mask = pathMask
}
  }


     let myPicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/14196150_10207770295835716_3510332720585393213_o.jpg?oh=fdb525410602f40f4735991b713e9c50&oe=596688E5")!))!
    let iv = UIImageView(image: myPicture)

  let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
   bezierPath.move(to: iv.center)
  bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxX, y: 0))
  bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxX, y: iv.frame.maxY))
  bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: iv.frame.maxY))
  bezierPath.addLine(to: .zero)
  bezierPath.close()

 iv.addMask(bezierPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread:

[Warp \ bend effect on a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863904/warp-bend-effect-on-a-uiview/20974947#20974947)

There are several solutions discussed, including using a Core Image filter, or building your own "mesh warp" using OpenGL.

There's also the [**Brad Larson open source framework GPUImage on Github**](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). You might be able to build a filter with that framework to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

when you have to display that type image you can use image filter core or you can try image masking..

Image core Filter: show in:

> https://www.appcoda.com/core-image-introduction

```
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-apply-photo-filters-with-core-image-in-swift--cms-27142
```

Image Masking:

https://www.innofied.com/implementing-image-masking-in-ios/

i am try my best..to provide solution..that is simple image

[image]

that is mask image that is gif type image

[image]

code that write

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let image = UIImage(named: "image.gif")
        let maskingImage = UIImage(named: "mask-image.gif")
        imageView.image = maskImage(image: image!, mask: maskingImage!)
    }

func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{

    let imageReference = image.cgImage
    let maskReference = mask.cgImage

    let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                            height: maskReference!.height,
                            bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                            bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                            bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                            provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)

    let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)

    let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)

    return maskedImage
}
```

Final Result
[image]

Comment: https://www.innofied.com/implementing-image-masking-in-ios/ This is exactly what I am looking for however it appears to be in swift2 and not swift 3

Comment: How to outlet a imageview first than the code will work if you just change the suggested edits.