# Masked image's Background color

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have used following code for masking

```
imgMask = UIImageView(image: image)
imgImage.mask = imgMask
```

Now, I want to change background color to yellow, like this:

[image: example]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what you done for changing image background color ?

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya I have used 

      `imgImage.backgroundColor = green

        imgImage.tintColor = red`

Comment: try to change imgMask background color i hope so its work

Comment: No, Its not Working @DivyeshGondaliya

Comment: can you post an image showing what exactly you want to achieve through image masking

Comment: can you just upload a image of your issue

Comment: you can refers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861078/how-to-stretch-image-into-custom-shape-swift3

Comment: I have uploaded an Image Blue one Portion is my Masked Image and I want Yellow color as a Background Color of Image

Comment: check you mask image background is transparent or not ? set your mask imageview to UIColor.clear and setyour main image view to yellow color @KhushbuDesai

Comment: if this not will be work then tray to this img.mask?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        img.mask?.tintColor = UIColor.yellow @KhushbuDesai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let templateImage = originalImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate)
myImageView.image = templateImage
myImageView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

Comment: hey! Thanks for helping but using this code its change image's tint color so that my original image is not appeared. I want to change Background color with my Original image . @Abdelahad

Answer (score 1):

Heres a small code snippet with background color change

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var trial: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mask = UIImage(named: "mask_image")
        let image = UIImage(named: "wallpaper")

        trial.image = self.maskImage(image: image!, withMask: mask!)
        trial.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    func maskImage(image: UIImage, withMask maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let maskRef = maskImage.cgImage
        let mask = CGImage(
            maskWidth: maskRef!.width,
            height: maskRef!.height,
            bitsPerComponent: maskRef!.bitsPerComponent,
            bitsPerPixel: maskRef!.bitsPerPixel,
            bytesPerRow: maskRef!.bytesPerRow,
            provider: maskRef!.dataProvider!,
            decode: nil,
            shouldInterpolate: false)
        let masked = image.cgImage!.masking(mask!)
        let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage: masked!)
        // No need to release. Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed
        return maskedImage
    }      
}
```